# How to optimise Groovy code?

Tags: optimization, groovy

There are lots of guides around the internet on how to optimise Java code, but not so much for Groovy. What are the Groovy-specific things to watch out for when a piece of Groovy code needs to run faster?

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary**: This answer is specific to non-[indy](http://groovy-lang.org/indy.html) Groovy code running on the Hotspot vm (OpenJDK, Oracle JVM) version 1.8. The indy option promises to improve dynamic calls a lot, but I don't have experience with it.

Standard disclaimer on any optimisation: **MEASURE FIRST!** The slowest part of the code is likely somewhere you did not expect. For JVM code I have used the [honest profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/honest-profiler), it has its limitations but for CPU-bound loads it is certainly much better than the profilers that depend on JVM checkpoints. And it is free.

Optimising Groovy code:

- Apply `@CompileStatic` to all the hot code! Make sure you don't miss an intermediate hot method somewhere. Without CompileStatic, the JVM's optimisation capabilities are useless.
- Avoid Groovy collection methods. Groovy collection methods (`each`, `collect`, etc) are slow because they use closures which [cannot be inlined](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225133928/http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-04-04-fixing-the-inlining-problem) properly by the JVM. Replace loops with Java-style for and for-each loops. For simple loops, this is just as readable as the Groovy syntax. For more complex cases look at the native Java collection methods or libraries like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki).
- Avoid closures if you can. Closure invocations are slow. Even if all your code is `@CompileStatic`, closure invocations still use Groovy's dynamic dispatch logic which is slow and blocks JVM optimisations. An alternative can be plain old Java inner classes with a single method. Unfortunately this is ugly, and Groovy does not support Java's anonymous class syntax. But be aware of the trade off.
- Avoid the `as` keyword. `as` does a potentially expensive conversion, which is different from just a cast. Instead of `foo as Bar`, write `(Bar) foo` if all you want is to cast. Groovy casts are still a bit more expensive than casts in Java, but they are much cheaper than conversions. Groovy casts also do a bit more than Java casts, such as converting between different numeric types. Conversions can be useful but only use them if you actually want a conversion and not just a cast, and their cost is worth the benefit in your case.
- Apply the general Java optimisation techniques. They usually work just as well on Groovy as on Java.

Stuff you don't need to bother with: (This is not Groovy specific, but still applies)

- Making everything final. If a local variable or parameter is not changed in practice the JVM will see that and optimise it as if it were final. Final static class members can still help in some cases, but the compiler will keep track of e.g. types just as well for a final and a non-final field.
- Spending a lot of effort on avoiding object allocation. Object allocation is very cheap. The first generation copying garbage collector copies only the live objects and ignores dead ones, so there is almost no garbage collection cost to short lived objects. And in general the (current) garbage collector does most of the heavy work on a separate thread, so unless all your processor cores are saturated the garbage collection itself does not slow down your (single threaded) code appreciably. Reusing objects can introduce nasty bugs and is often ugly. You only need to look at your object creation if profiling indicates you are spending a significant amount of time on garbage collections.